# gcc -nostdlib causes segmentation fault within SDL_OpenAudio()

Tags: c, linux, audio, gcc, sdl

When I compile the following code with gcc -nostartfiles or -nostdlib, running the resulting Program causes a crash deep within the Audio system, when SDL_OpenAudio() is called. Without this call everything works fine and even other Librarys work. When compiled without -nostartfiles/-nostdlib (and renaming _start to main and commenting the assembly exit call) It works fine.

My Question: What causes this dependency on the gcc startup code and how can I fix it without removing -nostartfiles / -nostdlib?

I'm compiling for linux 64 Bit on x86_64 with gcc 4.7.2

```
void _start()
{
    SDL_AudioSpec fmt;

    fmt.freq = 44100;
    fmt.format = AUDIO_S16;
    fmt.channels = 1;
    fmt.samples = 4096;
    fmt.callback = mixaudio;
    fmt.userdata = NULL;
    if ( SDL_OpenAudio(&fmt, NULL) < 0 ) SDL_Quit();
    SDL_PauseAudio(0);
    while(1){SDL_Delay(20);}

    asm("xorq %rax, %rax \n movq 42, %ebx \n int 0x80");
}
```

Comment: I guess SDL calls malloc() somewhere. The glibc sets up some data structures for it. Also, int 80 is for i386 and not for amd64 (where you use syscall instead).

Comment: Well, that makes sense.